# NGX-MQTT | MOSQUITTO

Tags: angular, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm using the `ngx-mqtt` library with Angular 8, and I'm not able to  to connect to the broker (MOSQUITTO). I'm using ubuntu server 20.04.
When I try to connect to a dns (https) I can, but when I try to connect to a local ip (192.168.X.X) I can't.
Settings in the Angular application:

app.module

```
export const MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS: IMqttServiceOptions = {
hostname: '192.168.xx.xx',
port: 9001,
path: '/ mqtt'
  };
MqttModule.forRoot (MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS),
```

app.component

```
this._mqttService.unsafePublish ('aaTEST', 'message', {qos: 1, retain: true});
```

Error message in the broker log:

```
Client <Unknow> closed its connection
```

Best Regards

Comment: Just to be sure: in your path variable is a space. Is that also the case in your setup?

Comment: @jBuchholz thanks for answering. in the code there is no blank space, it was an error when posting.

Comment: try to use code formatting for better reading and understanding your code.

Comment: @JanZahradník Ok

Comment: Are you saying it works with a hostname but not with an IP address? Assuming Secure Websockets then does the certificate also include a SAN entry for the IP address?